# Shell Script to display network info

Tags: linux, bash

I need help with a `shell script` to display my current IP Address and MAC Address with a "|" in between them like this:

```
IP Address:  | MAC Address:
```

So can this be done easily in a shell script?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about information security. It might be more on topic on stackoverflow.com because this site is about coding - but they expect to at least try yourself first and help with specific problems instead of doing all the coding for you as you expect here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Shell Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

IF=$(route | grep '^default' | grep -o '[^ ]*$')
IP=$(ip addr show $IF | awk '/inet / {print $2}' | cut -d/ -f 1)
MAC=$(ip link show $IF | awk '/ether/ {print $2}')

echo "IP Address: $IP | MAC Address: $MAC"
```

Look into grep, awk, and sed to learn more about text processing and doing more tasks like this.